# Dynamic Data Source at run time based on Active Directory account

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

I have a set of SSRS reports that I want to provide access to multiple customers. Each customer has their own database.  There is a shared data source that all the reports access.  Each customer's database has identical schema/objects, only the data is different. Each customer has an Active Directory login.

Is there a way for the Shared Data Source to dynamically change which database it connects to based on the user accessing the report? Is there a way using SSRS integrated with Sharepoint?

The only other solution I've seen is passing in the Server/Database as parameters, which would require an application and use of the web service.

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint Mode might offer some (AD) authentication and datasource stuff I don't know about, but you could combine the parameter solution you mention with the `[%UserId]` [global](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255216.aspx), and build a connection dynamically based on it.

Here's an alternative solution with a single source report, deployed once per client:

- create one report folder per database
- use a shared data source, one per database (located in that folder)
- on first deploy, configure the data source connection for each database
- set [`OverwriteDatasources`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155802.aspx) to false
- set up a deployment process (using multiple configurations, or perhaps a script) that deploys the source report to all customer folders
- update your site so each user gets to see a report from the corresponding customer folder

Comment: Thanks @Jeroen. It's not looking very promising on the Dynamic data source based on Active Directory.  I am afraid we'll be left to the option you suggested or creating a custom app.